# My project files are shown publicly when deployed by netlify and bundled with parcel config

Tags: javascript, deployment, netlify, parceljs

I have a plain javascript html project for a website. Used parcel to bundle and minimize the html and javascript files. When I run the `parcel build` command a **dist** folder is created with **[filename].hash.js** and **[filename].js.map** but HTML files stay same. I thought during the deployment netlify will directly take the files generated in the build folder but instead, it shows all the files after deploying.

[image]

I would like to know how to hide my javascript files in the website and use only files generated by parcel bundler. Do I need to make any special configuration in the Netlify or Parcel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to disable the source map in the parcel js config or in the build command in the package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build --no-source-maps"
  },
```

And make sure to use "npm run build" as a build command in the netlify.